# Json data not well formated error

Tags: html, angularjs, vb.net, web-services

json data not binding into table

controller code

```
 $http(
            {
                method: 'post',
                url: 'Service.asmx/WPGetDS',
                data: $.param({ as_sql: "select    * from testtab", strConKey: "Etech" }),
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {               
                var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
                $scope.dtDioSearch = myjson;
                console.log(myjson);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

Web Service Code

```
Public Sub WPGetDS(ByVal as_sql As String, ByVal strConKey As String)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim conGlobal As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strConKey).ConnectionString)
        Dim a(0) As String
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim dtDataTable As DataTable
        If conGlobal.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conGlobal.Open()
        Dim SDA = New SqlDataAdapter(as_sql, conGlobal)
        Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim data As New WPData
        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim lCmdSql, lCmdErr As New SqlCommand
        Try


            dtDataTable = New DataTable("Table")
            Dim dcolSrNo As DataColumn

            dcolSrNo = New DataColumn("SlNo")
            dcolSrNo.AutoIncrement = True
            dcolSrNo.AutoIncrementSeed = 1
            dcolSrNo.AutoIncrementStep = 1
            dtDataTable.Columns.Add(dcolSrNo)

            DS.Tables.Add(dtDataTable)
            SDA.Fill(DS, ("Table"))
            SDA.Dispose()

            data.Message = ConvertDataTableTojSonString(DS.Tables(0))

            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data.Message))
        Catch ex As Exception
            dt.Columns.Clear()
            dt.Columns.Add("Error")
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr.Item("Error") = ex.Message.Trim
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            DS.Tables.Add(dt)
            conGlobal.Close()

            data.Message = ConvertDataTableTojSonString(DS.Tables(0))
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data.Message))
        Finally
            If conGlobal.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conGlobal.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="table-responisive">
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Test</th>        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="erdata in dtDioSearch  track by $index">
        <td>{{erdata.SlNo}}</td>
        <td>{{erdata.Test}}</td>            
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Console Json data

```
[{"SlNo":1,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":2,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":3,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":4,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":5,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":6,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":7,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":8,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":9,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":10,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":11,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":12,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":13,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":14,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":15,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":16,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":17,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":18,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":19,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":20,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":21,"test":"test"},{"SlNo":22,"test":"test"}]
```

My problem is json data not bind to the html table. in firefox there was an error  shown not well-formed in console. please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of your success callback will be a JavaScript object containing many properties including a data property whose value is the parsed JavaScript object based on the JSON returned by your API. Trying to parse a JavaScript object will result in error.

Try modifying the success method to:

```
.success(function (response, status, headers, config) {               
   var myjson = response.data;
   $scope.dtDioSearch = myjson;
});
```

Comment: error occour in cosole     undefined
not well-formed

Comment: '}).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {

       var myjson = response.data;
       $scope.dtDioSearch = myjson;
       console.log(myjson);'

Comment: @VinodJohn if the JSON is exactly what you posted it is not likely to throw an error. Or maybe you posted a sample, but the real JSON might be containing weird invisible characters... try validating actual response in an [online json validator](http://jsonlint.com/). If not this error is coming from somewhere else in your application

Comment: @T J.. i just validate the json and result is valid json . then why the data is not binding the html table.

Comment: @VinodJohn can you use unminified version of angular and post the exact error? Else try replicating the issue in a [mcve] becuase the shared code doesn't even contain an `ng-app` directive so obviously it won't bind

Comment: @t j  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        $scope.dtDioSearch = [{"id": "1", "test": "this is a description"}];

Comment: the above code sucessfully executed. that means webservice return json is not an array.

Comment: @VinodJohn well you posted a JSON array in question... We only know what you share.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetJSon(ByVal dt As DataTable) As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        'Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt).ToList
        'Return JSONString

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                If col.DataType = GetType(Date) Then
                    Dim dtt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr(col).ToString())
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dtt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
                Else
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                End If

            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return rows
    End Function
```

@tj thank you for your support. the problem is json return string and i changed it to array list